# PHP Average day between list of dates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the average number of days from a list of dates with php but I can't find anything online so I thought I would try here. Here is what my msyql is output so far for me.

```
2016-01-28
2016-01-27
2016-01-20
2015-12-28
2015-12-12
2015-12-05
2015-12-01
2015-11-27
2015-11-21
2015-11-11
2015-11-03
2015-10-31
2015-10-27
2015-10-17
2015-10-05
2015-09-20
2015-09-14
2015-09-02
2015-08-26
2015-08-18
2015-08-14
2015-08-08
2015-07-29
2015-07-18
2015-07-08
2015-06-22
2015-06-18
2015-06-07
2015-05-15
2015-05-13
2015-05-12
2015-05-02
```

my code to get the dates:

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      echo $row['date']."<br>";

  }
```

I'm trying to get the average number of days between each output.... any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can u add your code php ?

Comment: Between each date and every other date? Or each date and the following date, or what?

Comment: Don't use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: Are you basically trying to find the standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2016-01-28'),
('2016-01-27'),
('2016-01-20'),
('2015-12-28'),
('2015-12-12'),
('2015-12-05'),
('2015-12-01'),
('2015-11-27'),
('2015-11-21'),
('2015-11-11'),
('2015-11-03'),
('2015-10-31'),
('2015-10-27'),
('2015-10-17'),
('2015-10-05'),
('2015-09-20'),
('2015-09-14'),
('2015-09-02'),
('2015-08-26'),
('2015-08-18'),
('2015-08-14'),
('2015-08-08'),
('2015-07-29'),
('2015-07-18'),
('2015-07-08'),
('2015-06-22'),
('2015-06-18'),
('2015-06-07'),
('2015-05-15'),
('2015-05-13'),
('2015-05-12'),
('2015-05-02');

SELECT x.*
     , DATEDIFF(MIN(y.dt),x.dt) diff 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.dt > x.dt 
 GROUP 
    BY x.dt;
+------------+------+
| dt         | diff |
+------------+------+
| 2015-05-02 |   10 |
| 2015-05-12 |    1 |
| 2015-05-13 |    2 |
| 2015-05-15 |   23 |
| 2015-06-07 |   11 |
| 2015-06-18 |    4 |
| 2015-06-22 |   16 |
| 2015-07-08 |   10 |
| 2015-07-18 |   11 |
| 2015-07-29 |   10 |
| 2015-08-08 |    6 |
| 2015-08-14 |    4 |
| 2015-08-18 |    8 |
| 2015-08-26 |    7 |
| 2015-09-02 |   12 |
| 2015-09-14 |    6 |
| 2015-09-20 |   15 |
| 2015-10-05 |   12 |
| 2015-10-17 |   10 |
| 2015-10-27 |    4 |
| 2015-10-31 |    3 |
| 2015-11-03 |    8 |
| 2015-11-11 |   10 |
| 2015-11-21 |    6 |
| 2015-11-27 |    4 |
| 2015-12-01 |    4 |
| 2015-12-05 |    7 |
| 2015-12-12 |   16 |
| 2015-12-28 |   23 |
| 2016-01-20 |    7 |
| 2016-01-27 |    1 |
+------------+------+
```

The average then is simply the average of diff, so:

```
SELECT AVG(diff)
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.*
            , DATEDIFF(MIN(y.dt),x.dt) diff 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.dt > x.dt 
        GROUP 
           BY x.dt
     ) a;

+-----------+
| AVG(diff) |
+-----------+
|    8.7419 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this, trying to add in where clause but it's throwing an error: `SELECT AVG(diff)
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.*
            , DATEDIFF(MIN(y.dt),x.dt) diff 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.dt > x.dt 
        WHERE x.name LIKE '%andy%'
        GROUP 
           BY x.dt
     ) a;`

Comment: name is not a column in my_table

Comment: it is in mine, i added

Comment: Unfortunately, without a data set, we're heading off into the realms of pure speculation.